# Update Adapter within BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to update my adapter when i press "vote" button that was define inside `getView()` method in my `EntertainerAdapter` that extends `BaseAdapter`.

So here my example, first a snippet of my `EntertainerListActivity` when i set the adapter with some values retrived from Parse.com:

```
// some code to retrive my objects from Parse.com
for (ParseObject ent : entertainers) {
String name = ent.getString("name");
int vote = ent.getInt("vote");
aList.add(new Entertainer(name, vote));}
EntertainerAdapter adapter = new EntertainerAdapter(EntertainerListActivity.this, aList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and than my `EntertainerAdapter`, i am just reporting a simplified version of `getView()` to underline my problem:

```
        vote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Entertainer");
            query.whereEqualTo("name", name.getText());
            query.whereEqualTo("surname", surname.getText());
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (object == null) {
                        Log.d("ZIG", "The getFirst request failed.");
                    } else {
                        object.put("vote", object.getInt("vote") + 1);
                        object.saveInBackground();
                        // OK Now i have to refresh my adapter
                        // I tried
                        notifyDataSetChanged(); // with no results

                        // than intent that start again my Activity
                        //Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, EntertainerListActivity.class);
                        //mActivity.startActivity(i);
                        // This works but i have a big issue when i press back button
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you are updating the data in parse and calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()`; But the data you passed to the adapter is still the same and that's the reason why you are not seeing any change. You should update the data in the adapter also.

```
vote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
          ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Entertainer");
          query.whereEqualTo("name", name.getText());
          query.whereEqualTo("surname", surname.getText());
          query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
          {
              public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)
              {
                  if (object == null)
                  {
                       Log.d("ZIG", "The getFirst request failed.");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        object.put("vote", object.getInt("vote") + 1);
                        object.saveInBackground();

                        // Update the local Entertainer object here
                        // entertainerObject.setVote(entertainerObject.getVote() + 1);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
               }
          });
     }
});
```